# How to ignore transparent place on hover event

Tags: html, css

How to ignore transparent place on hover event ? In the first picture i need ignore "THIS PLACE". I need hover on rhombus works only.

[image]

```
<img src='http://s30.postimg.org/xpd6gwla9/1_Copy.jpg' id="first">

#first:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You might be able to using an SVG element (not in an `<img>` tag), but with a normal image the bounding box will always be rectangular, and any box shadows or other styles will be applied to that box instead of the contours of your image.

Comment: Maybe me event listeners in javascript can know where is empty space on image?

Comment: It's possible if you insert your image into a `<canvas>` element and test the alpha value of the pixel clicked, but your box shadow will require a lot more work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using image you can **create your own rhombus** and then apply hover to it like below

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/6ebutyc5/)**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='diamond'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#diamond {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
#diamond:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: red;
}
#diamond:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}
#container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:3px solid;
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: added a `border` to the diamond and it seems to be throwing away on `hover` => [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ebutyc5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/S9sNU/9/)**

css

```
a {
    display:block;
    height:165px;
    width:165px;
    background:transparent;
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 37px;
}
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    background:url('http://s30.postimg.org/xpd6gwla9/1_Copy.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <div class="bg">
        <div><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No longer works and no explanation